# Loop and random photo generator -- not generating random photos

Tags: browser, express, browser-cache

I'm looping through users (with Express.js) and displaying cards for them. For the users without profile pictures, I'm using the random photo generator at http://lorempixel.com/. It pulls a random photo every time:

```
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
        <div class="user">   
          <div class="user-container">     
                <div class="img-container">  

                  <!-- Image User -->
                  <div class="img-user" id="<%= 'img-div' + user.id %>">

                    <% var picture = user.get("profilePictureMedium");
                       if (picture) { %>
                        <img id="<%= 'img-' + user.id %>" src="<%= user.get("profilePictureMedium").url() %>" width="220"                                             
                                       />
                    <%  } else { %>
                        <img id="<%= 'img-' + user.id %>" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/animals/" width="220"  >
                    <%  } %>
                  <!-- /Image User -->
```

What's happening is that the same photo is generated for every user without a profile photo. However, if I manually load `http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/animals/` into a browser window I'll get a different photo everytime.

I stuck in:

```
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/animals/" width="220" />
```

Outside of the loop and it pulled the same photo as the photo in the loop, so I suppose the browser is catching the result of the first call.

Is there a way to avoid this caching so that it calls and retrieves a random photo each time?

Comment: better to use microseconds,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common solution is to append a redundant query string to the url. For example:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/animals/?v=1404442966794" />
```

This random number could be the current timestamp or, perhaps better in this use case, the id for a given user, that way caching can still be utilized once an image has been acquired for a given user. i.e.

```
src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/animals/?v=<%= user.id %>"
```